# Get image src from external url using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to find image src from external url

This is my function:

```
<script>
function sompret_image_creator(url, ptitle)
{
    $.ajax(
        { 
        url: url, 
        success: function(data) {
            var img = $.parseHTML( data ).find("img"), 
                len = img.length; 
            if( len > 0 ){
                var src = img.first().attr("src"); // get id of first image
            } else {
                console.log("Image not found");
            }
            console.log(src);

            image_tag='<img src="'+src+'" alt="'+ptitle+'"/>';
            return image_tag;
        } 
    });
}
</script>
```

I have this error

> **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'find'**

Comment: What data do you get back? Can you not just do `$(data).find("img");`?

Comment: by any chance is it wrapped in `d`, like `data.d` instead of `data` ?

Comment: Yes, I would also suggest to do `$(data).find("img")` instead of `$.parseHTML( data ).find("img")`. Probably that work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data is only html, you need to wrap the $.parseHTML( data ) with $() and then do .find()

```
<script>
function sompret_image_creator(url, ptitle)
{
    $.ajax(
        { 
        url: url, 
        success: function(data) {
            var html = $.parseHTML( data ), 
                img = $(html).find("img"),
                len = img.length; 
            if( len > 0 ){
                var src = img.first().attr("src"); // get id of first image
            } else {
                console.log("Image not found");
            }
            console.log(src);

            image_tag='<img src="'+src+'" alt="'+ptitle+'"/>';
            return image_tag;
        } 
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much, but now i need to get the first src of .post class how can i make this ?

Comment: $(html).find('img.post').first().attr('src');

Comment: .post it's not the class of my images but of my div.

<div class="post">
<img src.... />
</div>

Comment: $(html).find('.post').find('img').first().attr('src');

Comment: I think you need this: $(html).find('.post').find('img:first');

Comment: look at your post, you can see just a return, this return is for the anonymous function not for the sompret_image_creator function

Comment: Oh, you can't do "return" cause it asynchronous. What are you going to do with that image tag?

Comment: smthg like document.write(sompret_image_creator(url, title));

Comment: So you need to do the "document.write" instead of the return.

Comment: I tried that but it delete all my code and put only the image tag

Comment: Where do you want to put the img tag? I think you need to lean more about js and jquery :\

Comment: if you have div with id you can do $('#myid').append(image_tag); to add the image tag.

Comment: or $('#myid').html(image_tag); if you wanr to replace all the content inside.

Comment: nop, i have div with class so i did this $('.sompret-image').prepend(image_tag)

but you know, all div have the same class, so the same img everywhere

Comment: So where do you want to put it?

Comment: just after this div <div class='sompret-image'>
ps: this dis is 24 times on my page

Comment: So after the first? second? third?

Comment: everywhere bro, every <div class='sompret-image'> has his image

Comment: So you need to go to the parent element. but I think your logic in your code wrong. Try to post it to jsfiddle.net

Comment: I would do it on server side.

Comment: I would too, but you know, i'm using blogger so no access to server side

Comment: okay bro i did it with the article ID :) Thank you very much!